# How can I optimize 'enumerate' when I have to search in a long pandas Series (> 15 M elements)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

I have a pandas Series that contains time information (floats that represent seconds), and I need to identify the index for which the time is greater than x for example. I'm currently using enumerate to do it, but I'm not sure it's the best way to do it, as it takes a little while to execute. I'd like to know if there's any vectorized way to perform this operation.

```py
index = [i for i, val in enumerate(df['time']) if val >= x][0]
```

Example Series:

```
time

0.0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1
```

Comment: yes, there is a vectorized way to do it. have you tried anything along those lines so far?

Comment: To answer: 1) *I need to identify the index* - you meant list of indexes? 2) *it takes a little while* - how much is that and what timing is acceptable?

Comment: No, this is the second approach that I've tried so far. The first one was to loop through it until I reached the value x.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest No, just the first element for which it occurs (I've edited the code). And it takes like 2 seconds (not acceptable when I have to do that operation like 500 times)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
df[df['time'] >= x].index
```

or

```py
np.nonzero(df['time'].values >= x)[0]
```

EDIT:
If you only need the first occurrence:

```py
np.argmax(df['time'].values >= x)
```

Comment: Thanks, both work like a charm. The solution using np.argmax is about 3 times faster than the first one proposed.

Answer (score 1):

To get only the **first** *index for which the time is greater than `x`*:

```
next(t[0] for t in df.itertuples() if t.time > x)
```